# Why Primitive specializations of the Supplier java 8

Tags: java

I searched on the internet but I didn't find any specific example for 'Primitive specializations of the Supplier'. When it should be used. As I see one reason IntSupplier guarantees that return value is an int but the Supplier not. If we use ParameterizedType it also guarantees. Is it affect the performance? Is there any example in the real world for usage of any Primitive specializations of the Supplier?

```
   1. IntSupplier intSupplier = () ->  20;
   2. Supplier integerSupplier = () ->  20; //can be int or any type
   3. Supplier<Integer> integerSupplier = () ->  20;
```

Comment: `IntSuplier` is used when you want to avoid autoboxing.

Comment: `2` uses raw types and should be generally avoided, your question regarding `1` and `3` still stands though.

Comment: @ibrahimKarayel but auto-boxing, more precisely auto-unboxing, is still happening, if you want it or not. You do not see any difference because it *auto*-unboxes ;)

Comment: autoboxing is done automatically for 3th case.

Comment: There is an overhead to autoboxing. It's small, but there, so yes, it affects performance and memory footprint.